# Tikzposter with smartdiagram

Tags: tikzposter, smartdiagram

I would like to use smartdiagram in tikzposter. I created a small test

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\smartdiagramset{}
\smartdiagram[descriptive diagram]{%
{test,
test
}}
\end{document}
```

but as soon as I change the class to tikzposter, I obtain the following error:

```
Error: Sorry, the requested layer 'backgroundlayer' is not part of the layer list. Please verify that you provided \pgfsetlayers and that 'backgroundlayer' is part of this list.
```

I guess it's because tikzposter load tikz already, but I didn't manage to fix this.

Comment: The error about the layers can be solved by reinserting the layers from tikzposter into the list from smartdiagram with `\pgfsetlayers{backgroundlayer,background,smart diagram arrow back,main,notelayer}`, but then the next error already awaits you...